# Automatic restart pc when working on odt file on ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04

I am facing a problem using odt file of LibreOffice writer in ubuntu 16.04 LTS. It is hanging then restarting automatically.

```
lsmod | grep drm 
drm_kms_helper 172032 1 i915
syscopyarea 16384 1 drm_kms_helper
sysfillrect 16384 1 drm_kms_helper
sysimgblt 16384 1 drm_kms_helper
fb_sys_fops 16384 1 drm_kms_helper
drm 401408 11 drm_kms_helper,i915
```

```
lspci | grep -Ei "VGA|Video|3D" 
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 530 (rev 06)
```

Comment: Did you tried to check your file at virustotal.com ? What is special about this odt-file? Did you received it from trustful place? Did you tried to open in LO on Windows? What version of LibreOffice do you use ?

Comment: Version: 5.1.6.2
Build ID: 1:5.1.6~rc2-0ubuntu1~xenial9
CPU Threads: 4; OS Version: Linux 4.15; UI Render: default; 
Locale: en-IN (en_IN); Calc: grou

Comment: all .odt file behave similarly, i.e., restart machine automatically.

Comment: What are your graphics adapter and drivers for it? Please add output of `lspci | grep -Ei "VGA|Video|3D"` and `lsmod | grep drm` to the question.

Comment: lsmod | grep drm
drm_kms_helper        172032  1 i915
syscopyarea            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysfillrect            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysimgblt              16384  1 drm_kms_helper
fb_sys_fops            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
drm                   401408  11 drm_kms_helper,i915

Comment: lspci | grep -Ei "VGA|Video|3D"
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 530 (rev 06)

Comment: Please open LibreOffice Options (via Tools → Options or <Alt>+<F12>) and compare them with [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NbTcN.png). I'm also running 16.04 LTS on integrated Intel graphics without OpenGL in LO. Do you have it enabled?

Comment: After reinstall the libreoffice this issue is solved